# mongoimport v3.2.4 hangs randomly while importing json with --jsonArray

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have a json file with an array of ~120K documents.
I'm importing the json file to a mongo collection

`mongoimport --db my-db --collection my_collection -j 4 file.json --jsonArray --batchSize 5 -v`

It stopped randomly and never finished. I tried to run with -v but couldn't see any useful log.

Comment: What is the error message you received in the console/ terminal?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved after upgrading mongo to the current latest version 3.2.11

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the issue for myfile which was arounf 1.5GB. I was to solve it using both `batchsize` and `numInsertionWorkers`.

```
mongoimport --db cam --collection cost --type json 
            --file /data/db/cost1/cost500000.json --jsonArray 
            --numInsertionWorkers 500 --batchSize 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try reducing the batchSize to 1 `--batchSize 1`

```
mongoimport --db my-db --collection my_collection -j 4 --file file.json --jsonArray --batchSize 1
```

You can also try increasing the `-j` parameter to `8` if you have that many logical cores.